# Is my topology/are my climate zones alright?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, hard-science, topography

This is my first try at worldbuilding, and I need some feedback. I've filled in what I hope are realistic climate zones, ocean currents and topology for this current state of the world, all done in illustrator. I've included images of the topology, climate zones and tectonic plate borders for reference. Colours used for climate map are in accordance to Koppen Climate Classification. Thanks so much in advance!  [image: Climate Map], [image: Topology Map], [image: Plate Borders]

EDIT: In response to answers, I have included some more details. This is a Pangea-like supercontinent, the northern tip reaches above 75 Degrees North, the southern tip reaches around 55/60 Degrees South.

Here's a key for the climate system:
Dark Blue: Tropical Rainforest
Mid Blue: Tropical Monsoon
Light Blue: Tropical Savanna
Red: Hot Desert
Orange: Hot Steppe
Yellow: Mediterranean
Pale Yellow: Cold Steppe
Pink: Cold Desert
Light Turquoise: Temperate Forests
Dark Turquoise: Taiga/Boreal
Light Green: Humid Subtropical
Lime: Oceanic
Dark Green: Temperate Rainforest
Light Grey: Polar Tundra
Dark Grey: Polar Ice Caps

I've also included an attempt at a pressure system. The first one is for summer in the northern hemisphere, the second is summer in the southern hemisphere. Is this okay?
[image: Northern Hemisphere Summer]
[image: Southern Hemisphere Summer]

Comment: This is a nice job, although I have doubts about that strip of desert on the eastern side. However, to properly deduce climates, you also need at least an estimate of precipitation, which in turn is going to call for a map of your planet's wind patterns. That is something that you have the means to do; if you want advice, I have a detailed guide in another answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102798/how-do-i-figure-out-my-planets-biomes-and-weather/102838#102838) to give you some tips on the wind patterns and precipitation. Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: Missing (1) scale and (2) geographic position. Those are *essential* parameters. Is this island 100 km wide, 1000 km wide, or 10,000 km wide? Is it placed at 60° latitude south, or smack on the Equator? (And the Koppen Climate Classification does not specify any colors; not sure what you mean by "colors in accordance to Koppen".)

Comment: @AlexP This is a full world map: look at the ocean currents, because those black straight lines double as the approximate 30/60 N/S latitude lines. We can assume this to be an Earth-sized planet (so circumference of about 40000km) if not specified, since a size gap large enough to have a significant impact on climates would entail a different gravitational pull and/or planetary composition; that's clearly not where this question is going. Failing to specify colors is a mistake, but he's likely looking at the main image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification).

Comment: @Palarran: The OP edited the question adding the missing information.

Comment: if in an earth like enviroment,, yes, but i would get the desert as a mesa desert, and then the desert, and a bit more mountains, as all the plates are fully touching, also some volcanic fields, and other biomes are do, in between each but you can't do that as it is quite hard ; ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biome might interest you

Comment: I'd advise looking at Artifexian's climate video if you haven't yet, it's got some nice step-by-step advice on how to get this right!
But otherwise I agree that this southern desert shouldn't stretch that far east. Also I think you need more oceanic in the north (western coast) and drop the eastern desert in the north too, it should be devolving monsoon climate (see China on Earth). I'm also not convinced by Cfb and Csa in the northeast.

Comment: it looks quite good. only it feels like a smaller island and yet it spans most of the globe. most moisture should have fallen out by the time it reaches the centre of such a large land mass.

Answer (score 1):

**You have done well you don't have to change anything as it is believable already.**

I have tried to model it in https://azgaar.github.io/Fantasy-Map-Generator/

You can download the map from the following link to look through the model I have made. You need to load it from that file into the Fantasy-Map-Generator to view it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INK9IBJQ_-zV7Az1tFLsabShu-xgWQvb/view?usp=sharing

Or you can make your own model on the website. Small changes in some values can chance a bunch of biomes.

[image]

Some things of note:

1. The mountains are hot and cold deserts.
2. South east of the mountain is a savanna.
3. The tropical forest is more to the east near the coast.
4. Between the tropical forest and the mountain is a tropical seasonal forest.
5. The southern desert is only on the east of the continent and grassland.

Comment: Upvoted for *actually using* AFMG. Every time I see a question like this, my first reaction is "did you try mocking it up in AFMG?", *exactly because* it does climate modeling as you've shown.